# JFxtras NullPointer when edit appointment

Tags: java, jfxtras

Hello I was trying to implement the jfxtras icalendaragenda in my project but when I edit an appointment and save or delete this appointment I get a NPE. Someone know why is this happening? I have seen some video tutorials and this error shouldn't be happening.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
package graphicInterface;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import jfxtras.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.AgendaDaySkin;
import jfxtras.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.AgendaWeekSkin;
import jfxtras.labs.icalendaragenda.scene.control.agenda.ICalendarAgenda;
import jfxtras.labs.icalendarfx.VCalendar;

public class ControllerAgendaPatients implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private BorderPane container;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton pWeek;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton nWeek;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton day;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton week;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton month;

    private ICalendarAgenda agenda;

    private void createAgenda() {
        VCalendar vcalendar = new VCalendar();
        agenda = new ICalendarAgenda(vcalendar);
        container.setCenter(agenda);
    }

    @FXML
    void onClickDayView(ActionEvent event) {
        this.agenda.setSkin(new AgendaDaySkin(agenda));
    }

    @FXML
    void onClickMonthView(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void onClickWeekView(ActionEvent event) {
        this.agenda.setSkin(new AgendaWeekSkin(agenda));
    }

    @FXML
    void onNextWeekClick(ActionEvent event) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = agenda.getDisplayedLocalDateTime().plus(Period.ofWeeks(1));
        agenda.setDisplayedLocalDateTime(ldt);
    }

    @FXML
    void onPreviousWeekClick(ActionEvent event) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = agenda.getDisplayedLocalDateTime().minus(Period.ofWeeks(1));
        agenda.setDisplayedLocalDateTime(ldt);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        this.createAgenda();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jfxtras.labs.icalendaragenda.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.base24hour.editors.EditDisplayableTabPane.removeEmptyProperties(EditDisplayableTabPane.java:76)
    at jfxtras.labs.icalendaragenda.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.base24hour.editors.EditLocatableTabPane.removeEmptyProperties(EditLocatableTabPane.java:64)
    at jfxtras.labs.icalendaragenda.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.base24hour.editors.EditDisplayableTabPane.handleSaveButton(EditDisplayableTabPane.java:68)
    at jfxtras.labs.icalendaragenda.internal.scene.control.skin.agenda.base24hour.editors.EditLocatableTabPane.handleSaveButton(EditLocatableTabPane.java:35)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: I'll ping David, the writer of icalendar

Comment: OK thank you very much